# Can't redirect https non-www to www on Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https

So, I operate a few domains, and a few months ago I started switching all of them to SSL.

On my DNS console (Namecheap), I redirect all traffic to https & www, at least in theory.

In my Apache config, I have a series of port 80 Virtual hosts, that redirect http to https and www.

my ssl virtualhosts all serve https://www.example.com as well as https://example.com.

All my stuff is in the www subdomains.

I noticed https&non-www just times out on all domains.

So I tried a rewrite rule in my htaccess, something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

# v second thing i tried
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# v 1st thing i tried
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
#RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

A separate virtual host that redirected traffic, sorta like this:

```
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerName example.com

                Redirect / https://www.example.com/

                # Please imagine the Let's encrypt blob here.
        </VirtualHost>
```

All to no avail.

I'm a bit lost, I see solutions on the internet, they basically do not work, or I might not be implementing them properly. Who knows. (It's a figure of speech I personally don't but it'd be nice if you guys did!)

Just to clarify again, http non-www as well as http www redirection to https&www both work just fine. It's only https&non-www that fails, it times out on me.

Can you help my out? 
Thank you in advance.

Edit: Pasting all of the config as it is as of right now so you guys can get a better picture. The .htaccess is slightly modified because I've been testing on this particular website but it's roughly the same as every other .htaccess I have because I really like this config, so here it goes:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace8

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

</IfModule>


# Client Cache-control policy:
# Public Cache everything for 1 week (public: can be cached by proxies.)
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|pdf|css|js)$">
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Expires caching.
# Replicates the same policy seen in the Cache-control section.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|js|css|pdf)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 week"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

And, heres my little example.conf that I have in /var/www/apache2/sites-enabled, again, roughly similar to the others:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # This works amazing.
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAlias example.com

        Redirect / https://www.example.com/
    </VirtualHost>


    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.example.com # Works
        ServerAlias example.com # Doesn't work no matter what.


        DocumentRoot "/var/www/example"

        Options +FollowSymLinks 

            <Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Directory "/var/www/example">
        Options IncludesNOEXEC
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </Directory> 



        #LogLevel info ssl:warn # trace8.... trace1, debug, info, notice, warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # The lets encrypt blob.
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem

        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

EDIT: My apologies I realized that LogLevel can't be configured in .htaccess and moved it to my virtualhost otherwise my config is identical now and I'm testing it.

EDIT: Here's the log after I did that and requested https&non-www resulting in a timeout:

```
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:32.829860 2019] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21313] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51250] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e70a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/example/ -> 
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:32.829900 2019] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21313] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51250] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e70a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri ''
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:32.829921 2019] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 21313] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51250] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e70a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] RewriteCond: input='www.example.com' pattern='^example.com$' [NC] => not-matched
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:32.829927 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 21313] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51250] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e70a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] pass through /var/www/example/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:32.830005 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 21313] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51250] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71dd0a0/subreq] [perdir /var/www/example/] pass through /var/www/example/index.html
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:32.830044 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 21313] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51250] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71dd0a0/subreq] [perdir /var/www/example/] pass through /var/www/example/index.cgi
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:32.830072 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 21313] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51250] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71dd0a0/subreq] [perdir /var/www/example/] pass through /var/www/example/index.pl
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:32.830100 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 21313] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51250] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71dd0a0/subreq] [perdir /var/www/example/] pass through /var/www/example/index.php
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:33.867992 2019] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21314] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51252] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e70a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/example/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css -> wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css, referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:33.868055 2019] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21314] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51252] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e70a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css', referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:33.868074 2019] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 21314] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51252] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e70a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] RewriteCond: input='www.example.com' pattern='^example.com$' [NC] => not-matched, referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:33.868080 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 21314] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51252] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e70a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] pass through /var/www/example/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css, referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:33.936995 2019] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21314] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51252] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e30a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/example/wp-content/themes/portfolio-web/assets/library/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css -> wp-content/themes/portfolio-web/assets/library/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css, referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:33.937035 2019] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21314] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51252] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e30a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'wp-content/themes/portfolio-web/assets/library/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css', referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:33.937055 2019] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 21314] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51252] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e30a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] RewriteCond: input='www.example.com' pattern='^example.com$' [NC] => not-matched, referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:33.937067 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 21314] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51252] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e30a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] pass through /var/www/example/wp-content/themes/portfolio-web/assets/library/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css, referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:33.939182 2019] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21313] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51250] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e30a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/example/wp-content/themes/portfolio-web/assets/library/Font-Awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css -> wp-content/themes/portfolio-web/assets/library/Font-Awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css, referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:33.939212 2019] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21313] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51250] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e30a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'wp-content/themes/portfolio-web/assets/library/Font-Awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css', referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:33.939231 2019] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 21313] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51250] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e30a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] RewriteCond: input='www.example.com' pattern='^example.com$' [NC] => not-matched, referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:33.939260 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 21313] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51250] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e30a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] pass through /var/www/example/wp-content/themes/portfolio-web/assets/library/Font-Awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css, referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:34.036167 2019] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21312] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51258] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e70a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/example/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.min.js -> wp-includes/js/admin-bar.min.js, referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:34.036236 2019] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21312] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51258] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e70a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'wp-includes/js/admin-bar.min.js', referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:34.036267 2019] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 21312] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51258] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e70a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] RewriteCond: input='www.example.com' pattern='^example.com$' [NC] => not-matched, referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:34.036279 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 21312] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51258] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e70a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] pass through /var/www/example/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.min.js, referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:34.119597 2019] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21312] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51258] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e30a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/example/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/portfolioyo2.jpg -> wp-content/uploads/2019/09/portfolioyo2.jpg, referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:34.119667 2019] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21312] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51258] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e30a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'wp-content/uploads/2019/09/portfolioyo2.jpg', referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:34.119682 2019] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 21312] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51258] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e30a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] RewriteCond: input='www.example.com' pattern='^example.com$' [NC] => not-matched, referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:34.119687 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 21312] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51258] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e30a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] pass through /var/www/example/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/portfolioyo2.jpg, referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:34.122833 2019] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21311] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51288] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e70a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/example/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/laptop-1209008.jpg -> wp-content/uploads/2019/01/laptop-1209008.jpg, referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:34.122907 2019] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21311] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51288] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e70a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'wp-content/uploads/2019/01/laptop-1209008.jpg', referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:34.122933 2019] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 21311] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51288] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e70a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] RewriteCond: input='www.example.com' pattern='^example.com$' [NC] => not-matched, referer: https://www.example.com/
[Fri Sep 20 10:20:34.122941 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 21311] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client 188.26.215.200:51288] 188.26.215.200 - - [www.example.com/sid#7f44b72a56b8][rid#7f44b71e70a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/example/] pass through /var/www/example/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/laptop-1209008.jpg, referer: https://www.example.com/
```

Comment: If you try the above virtual host config, what is the result of testing https&non-www, just a timeout?

Comment: Do you mean an actual request timeout - or a “too many redirects” error maybe? And if a timeout - when does it occur, before or after the redirect? Use your browser dev tools, network panel, to check.

Comment: @04FS regular timeout. It times out while still in example.com. The specific site I'm testing on is Wordpress 5.2.3. on php 5.6 but the problem happens in the other sites as well, all are 5.6 and they're mostly laravel & wordpress.

Comment: Well, can’t recommend much more right now other than that you enable rewrite logging, and see if that helps shed some light on the issue. (Or give a clear and full description of what the current setup is, because with so many mentions of different things you tried, probably no one here knows what the actual, current state of things is.)

Comment: Okay, hold on just a minute I will try that and come back with all of my apache config if I still don't have a clue. Btw @DusanBajic I tried the virtualhost thing again it results in just another plain vanilla timeout :/

Comment: Are you sure that your `example.com` resolves to the same ip address as `www.example.com`?

Comment: @04FS I just updated with the log generated by a request to / after changing the config

Comment: @DusanBajic omg... example.com resolves to an IP I don't know at all (!) while www.example.com resolves to my server. What's most puzzling then is why http&non www would work....

Comment: the ip belongs to namecheap.

Comment: I have a theory, I think that namecheap is trying to do the redirection, as I told it to do in my domain tab, but it fails, because it doesn't have my ssl certificate. if this is correct, this should be solved if I tell namecheap to send "@" to my server and then managing the traffic there. Since DNS settings take a while to change, I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Problem solved!